# How to link Url.Action to a specific controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url.action, routeconfig

I have a menu with a number of selectable options within the menu, but for some reason if I select any of these items I am always redirected to the controller method of the last action which is the logout page.

My code for the list is the following:

```
<li class="edit">
    <i class="icon fa fa-cog"></i>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Manage")">My Account</a>
</li>

<li class="edit">
     <i class="icon fa fa-cog"></i>
     <a href="@Url.Action("Users", "Administrator")">Admin Tool</a>
</li>

<li class="edit">
     @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })){
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
}
```

All of those actions happen to always go the the logout method no matter the order that I place them in.

Also I do not know whether this affects anything, however in my route config I have the following:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Maybe the reason that the controller methods are not found is because the route only mentions the account controller?

Comment: Your route config looks ok.I think the main culprit is your @Html.BeginForm.

Comment: I see. Good to hear that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, that's should not be a problem. The `default` route values shows where the request must go if no values are specified for the parameters mentioned in the `url`. If you have authorization in your project, try decorating the actions you are trying to get to with the `'[AllowAnonymous]'`  or `Authorize(Roles='a user role')]`

Comment: Yeah this was it thanks a lot :) I was removing the authentication for specific users but forgetting to apply the allow anonymous part.